# ESLint configuration for rule "eqeqeq" is invalid

Tags: javascript, npm, eslint

When using the following .eslintrc file, eslint runt OK:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parser: 'babel-eslint',
  parserOptions: {
    sourceType: 'module'
  },
  extends: 'airbnb-base',
  plugins: [
    'html'
  ],
  'rules': {
    'import/no-unresolved': 0,
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 2 : 0
  }
}
```

However when I change to

```
extends: 'standard',
```

instead of

```
extends: 'airbnb-base',
```

I get the following error on build:

```
ERROR in ./src/main.js
Module build failed: Error: standard:
    Configuration for rule "eqeqeq" is invalid:
    Value "always,[object Object]" has more items than allowed.
```

I have no equality operations in the main.js file.

I installed standard post airbnb-base using:

```
npm install --save-dev eslint-config-standard eslint-plugin-standard eslint-plugin-promise
```

I am using elsint 3.17.0

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is usually happens when configuration that you are using was created for different version of ESLint. Maybe you installed older "standard" package that relies on older version of ESLint? This rule was last time updated in version 3.3.0 so if version of standard predates that, you might have no longer supported configuration. You should verify both version of "standard" that you are using, as well as double check version of ESLint itself.